Hibernation in Ubuntu 22.04 vs 18.04
Since pm-hibernate does not seem to work in Ubuntu 22.04 and hibernate does not exist (and is not downloadable), how can one save the working window setup after reboot? hibernate and pm-hibernate did work in Ubuntu 18.04.

You've provided no specifics; Ubuntu 18.04 was, and Ubuntu 22.04 is a LTS meaning you had kernel stack choice, and this in itself can make a difference in hibernation... Ubuntu 18.04 was the 2018-April release where as Ubuntu 22.04 is the newer 2022-April release, so the latter has newer software (beyond the obvious of 18.04 reaching EOSS or EOL depending on architecture last year). There is sizeable difference in software stack due to time between systems (newer hardware will like newer software often, older hardware can be easier with older software stack).
